# carry out a system-supportive propaganda function

Tags: nouns

*Manufacturing Consent: The Political Economy of the Mass Media (1988), by Edward S. Herman and Noam Chomsky, proposes that the mass communication media of the U.S. "are effective and powerful ideological institutions that **carry out a system-supportive propaganda function**, by reliance on market forces, internalized assumptions, and self-censorship, and without overt coercion", by means of the propaganda model of communication.*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manufacturing_Consent

I am a little bit confused by the passage in bold from the above Wikipedia excerpt. Is it possible to paraphrase it as "MM carry out a system that functions as supportive propaganda…" "System supportive propaganda function" – I am not sure wich word is the noun and which attribute.

Comment: **system-supportive propaganda** is propaganda that supports the System. The System is the complex of entrenched powers (military, industrial, corporate, political parties, etc).

Comment: The noun phrase **system-supportive propaganda** is used adjectivally to modify **function**. The media, it is alleged, carry out a specific function. Which function?  The function of producing propaganda that supports the System, a **system-supportive propaganda function**.  I find this kind of writing deplorable, but that's just my personal opinion.  "to carry out a function *by reliance*" is the phrase of someone who has  a feeble command of verbs.

Comment: @TRomano Hmm ... I'm not convinced that *system-supportive* modifies *propaganda*; it seems to me more likely that it modifies *propaganda function*--they carry out a propaganda function which supports the system. ... But in this context it may not matter.

Comment: @StoneyB. I agree, **system-supportive** and **propaganda** can be parsed as separate adjectives each modifying **function**.  a **propaganda function** supportive of the system.  But it can also be parsed like **hard-boiled egg sandwich**. What makes your reading more likely is that the sandwich cannot be hard-boiled, whereas the function can be supportive.

Comment: *The role of the media is to prop up the powers-that-be by producing pro-System propaganda.*  Rubber baby-buggy bumpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHORT ANSWER:
The hyphen in *system-supportive* signals that these two words constitute a single semantic unit, and suggests that they are in a 'non-canonical' sequence. We readily parse this as *supportive of the system*.

LONGER ANSWER:
In English noun phrases a modifying phrase which precedes the head noun must have its own head on its right end; a modifying phrase in which a complement (or modifier) follows the head must be placed after the head noun.<sup>†</sup>

<sub>*In these examples the head of the noun phrase is in boldface, the modifying phrase is in italics, and the head of the modifying phrase is in bold italics. * marks an ungrammatical construction.*</sub>

> *  A melancholy ***defeated*** by poverty **man**
>   <sup>ok</sup> A melancholy **man** ***defeated*** by poverty.
>
> *  The ***sweeping*** her porch elderly **woman**
>   <sup>ok</sup> The elderly **woman** ***sweeping*** her porch

This constraint may be evaded by inverting the modifying phrase to set the complement (or modifier) before the head. In writing it is customary to hyphenate these inverted phrases as a signal to the reader that something uncoventional is going on:

> <sup>ok</sup> A melancholy *poverty-**defeated*** **man**.
>   <sup>ok</sup> The elderly *porch-**sweeping** **woman**.

That's what's happening in your example. "A system-supportive propaganda function" is a propaganda function *supportive of the system*. The preposition *of* is deleted because its function is grammatical, not locative: the transformation of the the verb *support* into the adjective *supportive* requires *of* to mark *the system* as the object of *support*, but this relationship is implicit in the inverted phrase.

ADDED:
TRomano raises the question of whether we are to parse the relationship between *system-supportive* and *propaganda function* as 'stacked modification* or *submodification* (the terms are from *The Cambridge Grammer of the English Language*, 547-8). That is, should we read this as

1. *a function of producing system-supportive propaganda,* or as
2. *a propaganda function which is system-supportive*?

The question is interesting, but probably unresolvable. My gut feel is that 2. is more likely, because attributive nouns default to 'compounding' with their heads—a *competent company manager* is taken to be someone who exhibits competence in managing a company, not a manager of a competent company. But 1. is possible. I doubt, frankly, that Herman and Chomsky gave any thought to the difference: ambiguity is the polemicist's friend.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>There are to be sure established phrases like *ready-to-wear* which violate this principle; but they are rare, and in careful writing they are always hyphenated—again, to signal the unconventional structure.</sub>